# Application wait for Windows profile to be created

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, windows-7, user-profile

I have a WPF VB.NET 3.5 application which we have set to run at login via GPO (Windows 7, AD 2003/2008), when this application runs on user login I finding that it is failing when the user has not logged into the PC before and the profile needs to be created.

In our environment we use redirected folders to point folders such as Favorites and AppData (Global) to a network share.  My application copies files and folders to these redirected folders.  When my application is processing the folder and file copy code, I am seeing exceptions appear in my log file that the folder doesn't exist.

I have added the following bits of code to the top of my Window_Loaded method, which checks that the drives exist, and thinking that explorer runs when the profile has been created, I have also put in a check that this process exists.

```
Do Until checkProcessRunning("Explorer") = True AND _
   Directory.Exists("U:\") AND Direcotry.Exists("S:\")
   Thread.Sleep(100)
Loop
```

However, even with this in place I am still experiencing the issue of folders not being present.

One such folder I need is `%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`.  The Exception I am getting is `Could not find part of the path`.

What I am hoping for is some guidance or suggestions on how people have overcome this type of problem in the past, or what I am I missing, am I heading in the right direction or completely missing the mark?

Greatly appreciate any assistance given.

Matt

Comment: Have you tried having your application wait in a loop until the profile has been loaded?